# Twillio - get contents of incoming SMS

Tags: php, sms, twilio, webhooks

I'm following [Twillio's guide on responding to incoming SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-php).

Everything works as expected. I'm getting the webhook and the reply is sent to a verified number (I'm using a trial account).

The problem I'm having is getting the contents of the incoming message. I tried to get the contents through `$_POST` and `php://input` but both are empty. I want to get the contents in order to send to our info mailbox.

This is my replyToSMS.php:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-master/src/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\TwiML\MessagingResponse;

$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$sms = json_decode($rest_json, true);


$fh = fopen("log_post.txt","w");
foreach($sms as &$item) {
    fwrite($fh, $item) or die("died");
}
fclose($fh);

$response = new MessagingResponse();
$response->message("The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!");
print $response;

?>
```

I followed this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258103/twilio-how-to-send-an-sms-based-on-body-of-incoming-message) and the suggestions from the Twillio evangelist but I couldn't find a way there to get contents to be visible on the php code level rather than on the XML level

What am I missing here?

Comment: Those docs show the incoming message as being in `$_REQUEST['Body']`. Any luck with that?

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for pointing that out. Don't know how I missed it. Finally managed to get the contents of the incoming SMS and log it.

Comment: Glad that helped. The likely reason it's in `$_REQUEST` but not `$_POST` is that you've got your endpoint set in the Twilio console to take GET requests instead of POST requests. You probably want to tweak that.

Comment: The webhook is configured to send a post request. That’s what I see in ngrok logs in realtime and what I see in Twillio debugger. So I immediately assumed it would be in post. But all good now thanks a bunch @ceejayoz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many thanks to @ceejayoz who pointed out the answer. The docs mention that`$_REQUEST['Body']` contains the contents of the incoming message.

So it's not neither in `$_POST` nor in `php://input`. It's in `$_REQUEST` which is the object that contains all the data that is sent by Twillio webhook as it sends the API request to your server endpoint.

These are fields that the Request object contains:

```
ApiVersion: "2010-04-01"
SmsSid: "**********************************************"
SmsStatus: "received"
SmsMessageSid: "*******************************************"
NumSegments: "1"
From:"+1*************"
ToState: "NY"
MessageSid"***************************************"
AccountSid: "*********************************"
ToZip: ""
FromCountry: "US"
ToCity: ""
FromCity: ""
To: "+1**********"
FromZip: ""
Body: "Test"
ToCountry: "US"
FromState: ""
NumMedia: "0"
```

Comment: Bless you for posting the answer.